# How can I create a new column in a table to show only specific data from another column using SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, multiple-columns

I am trying to figure out how to create a new column in a table that will be labelled as Release_Year and that will only show the year that each movie was released.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN1AO.jpg)

I have not attempted to run a query as I do not know where to begin.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using bigquery

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new column of type int.

```
ALTER TABLE `projectID.datasetID.movie_table`
ADD COLUMN Release_Year int64;
```

Then you need to fill the column with values, you can do this using a `merge` statement. We also use a group by to ensure we have unique mappings.

```sql
merge into `projectID.datasetID.movie_table` as target_table
using (
select
movie_title,
extract(year from release_date) as release_year
from
`projectID.datasetID.movie_table`
group by
movie_title,
release_year) as mapping
on
mapping.movie_title = target_table.movie_title
when matched
then
update set target_table.release_year = mapping.release_year
```

This is untested but the general idea should work.

Comment: Brilliant that worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Could you recommend where I could learn and improve at SQL?

Comment: If this answer was the correct solution please mark it as the accepted solution so others who encounter the same issue can see the correct solution!

To learn the basics of SQL: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/sql/ 
Then you will want to learn BigQuery-specific syntax and commands, I'm sure there are resources available from a quick google.